# vim - colorscheme is not setting background color correctly

Tags: vim, background, color-scheme

I am trying to set [nightowl](https://github.com/haishanh/night-owl.vim) theme for vim, however it seems to partially render. The syntax is colored properly, however the background is appearing black.

My vimrc looks like this:

```
" automatic installation of vim-plug, if it's not available
if empty(glob('~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim'))
  silent !curl -fLo ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim --create-dirs
        \ https://raw.githubusercontent.com/junegunn/vim-plug/master/plug.vim
  autocmd VimEnter * PlugInstall --sync | source $MYVIMRC
endif

" plugins
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'haishanh/night-owl.vim'
call plug#end()

if (has("termguicolors"))
  set termguicolors
endif

syntax enable
colorscheme night-owl
```

and :scriptnames

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: ~/dotfiles/vim/plugins.vim
  4: ~/.vim/autoload/plug.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim
 11: ~/dotfiles/vim/colors.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 13: ~/.vim/plugged/night-owl.vim/colors/night-owl.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim
 19: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 20: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 21: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/vim.vim
 27: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/vim.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/vim.vim
 29: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/ruby.vim
 30: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/python.vim
```

What it should look like:
[night-owl-theme-vim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQNnU.png)

What it is looking like right now:
[my-messed-up-night-owl-them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO2du.png)

Answer (score 0):

Nightowl uses the following definition for the background:

```
hi Normal guifg=#d6deeb ctermfg=253 guibg=#011627 ctermbg=233 gui=NONE cterm=NONE
```

For me (in gnome-terminal), that terminal background value (`233`) also renders as almost pitch-black. You may want to tweak the value to a lighter shade (e.g. `235`), by duplicating the `:normal` command and putting it after `:colorscheme`.

As this is still an indexed 256-color palette, some terminals may also allow to change the mapping to the actual RGB colors. I guess that also explains the discrepancy you see in the screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

By default Vim doesn't enables XTerm RGB colors (unless you're using gVim). You have to set it manually. Put this to your `.vimrc`

```
syntax enable

if has('termguicolors')
    set termguicolors
    set t_Co=256

    " XTerm true colors
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif

colorscheme night-owl
```